# How to interpret error TS2345 in the context of Vue dynamic classes?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a Vue3/Vite/TS application that works fine when running in `npm run dev` but fails to build because of error `TS2345`. I understand that this is an error related to typing, but I cannot wrap my head around it to understand **where** exactly the error is.

```
transforming (15) node_modules\@vue\reactivity\dist\reactivity.esm-bundler.src/TimesView.vue:15:18 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ key: () => number; id: string; class: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLAttributes & ReservedProps & Record<string, unknown>'.
  Type '{ key: () => number; id: string; class: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ReservedProps'.
    Types of property 'key' are incompatible.
      Type '() => number' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol | undefined'.

15                 
<div 
v-for="hourAtDefaultCity in [...Array(24).keys()].map(x => locTime(x, city.timezone))" 
:key="hourAtDefaultCity.toUnixInteger" 
id="hour" 
class="flex justify-center place-content-between text-xl grow" 
:class="{ 'bg-gray-300 text-gray-400': isNightLocallyForHourAtDefaultCity(hourAtDefaultCity.hour, city.timezone), 'bg-sky-100 text-sky-900': !isNightLocallyForHourAtDefaultCity(hourAtDefaultCity.hour, city.timezone) }"
>
```

Going from the bottom of the stack, I understand that the error is actually about `() => number` (so the returned value of a function which is expected to be a `number`) that is not  assignable to to a set of types 'string | number | symbol | undefined'. This is what I do not understand: `number` is one of the types.

The declaration of `isNightLocallyForHourAtDefaultCity` is as follows:

```
const locTime = (hour: number, timezone: string): DateTime => DateTime.fromISO(`${hour.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:00`, { zone: defaultTimezone.value }).setZone(timezone)
const isNightLocallyForHourAtDefaultCity = (hour: number, timezone: string): boolean => locTime(hour, timezone).hour < config.value.dayStartHour || locTime(hour, timezone).hour > config.value.dayEndHour
```

Where would I have the `() => number` TS complains about?

EDIT: just to be on the safe side, below is the complete code of the component (including the parts that TS doe snot complain about and of course everything I mentioned above)

```js
<template>
    <div class="flex justify-center h-screen">
        <div class="flex flex-row" id="cities">
            <div v-for="city in config.cities" :key="city.name" class="flex flex-col shrink-0 justify-between">
                <div class="cityName items-center mb-3 flex flex-col" :class="{ 'bg-green-200': city.name === config.defaultCity }">
                    <div class="text-center font-extrabold text-4xl" :style="maxCityNameSizeStyle" ref="maxCityNameSizeRefs">
                        {{ city.name }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                        {{ now.setZone(city.timezone).toFormat('HH:mm') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- iterate over the column of hours of the default city, adapting the dispayed to the city tz -->
                <div v-for="hourAtDefaultCity in [...Array(24).keys()].map(x => locTime(x, city.timezone))" :key="hourAtDefaultCity.toUnixInteger" id="hour" class="flex justify-center place-content-between text-xl grow" :class="{ 'bg-gray-300 text-gray-400': isNightLocallyForHourAtDefaultCity(hourAtDefaultCity.hour, city.timezone), 'bg-sky-100 text-sky-900': !isNightLocallyForHourAtDefaultCity(hourAtDefaultCity.hour, city.timezone) }">
                    <span>⸺</span>
                    <span class="font-bold">{{ hourAtDefaultCity.toFormat('HH') }}</span>
                    <span>:</span>
                    <span>{{ hourAtDefaultCity.toFormat('mm') }}</span>
                    <span>⸺</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <time-bar :now="now" :config="config" :maxCityNameSize="maxCityNameSize" :defaultTimezone="defaultTimezone"></time-bar>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { DateTime } from "luxon";
import { onMounted, ref, watch } from 'vue'
import TimeBar from './TimeBar.vue'
import { config } from "./config";

const props = defineProps({
    defaultTimezone: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Etc/UTC'
    }
})
const defaultTimezone = ref(props.defaultTimezone)

// global current time, updated every X seconds
const now = ref(DateTime.now())
// setInterval(() => (now.value = DateTime.now()), 1000)

// compute the time to display based on the hour number of the other ones
const locTime = (hour: number, timezone: string): DateTime => DateTime.fromISO(`${hour.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:00`, { zone: defaultTimezone.value }).setZone(timezone)
const isNightLocallyForHourAtDefaultCity = (hour: number, timezone: string): boolean => locTime(hour, timezone).hour < config.value.dayStartHour || locTime(hour, timezone).hour > config.value.dayEndHour

const maxCityNameSize = ref(0)
const maxCityNameSizeStyle = ref('')

watch(() => config.value, () => console.log(`config in times view changed: ${JSON.stringify(config.value)}`))

onMounted(() => {
    // style for the width of the column
    maxCityNameSize.value = Math.max(...Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.cityName')).map((x) => x.clientWidth))
    maxCityNameSizeStyle.value = `width: ${maxCityNameSize.value}px`

    // location.href = 'http://localhost:5173/?cities=San_Diego,America/Los_Angeles;Paris,Europe/Paris;Boston,America/New_York;Pune,Asia/Kolkata;Tokyo,Asia/Tokyo;UTC,Etc/UTC&default=UTC'
})
</script>
```

Comment: No, you are trying to assign a **function** that returns a number to `string | number | symbol | undefined`. You'll have to show us where you actually pass the props because this is not enough code to know.

Comment: @kelsny: Thanks for your comment. I am trying to digest it but I fail to understand what props you are talking about. Props to the component? I added the whole code of the component just to be on the safe side, but it does not seem to me that the error is related to the props. Not to mention that I do not see where I am using a **function**  as a parameter or result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in a function as `key` in

```html
<div
  v-for="..."
  :key="hourAtDefaultCity.toUnixInteger"
  ...
```

Typescript is telling you that `key` has to be `string | number | symbol | undefined`.

I think you want to execute the function instead of passing it in:

```
:key="hourAtDefaultCity.toUnixInteger()"
```

Comment: Ahhhh! Thanks a lot! This is the effect of switching time libraries, in the previous one it was an attribute, and here it is a function.